# How to handle taps on many UIButtons in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to make an app in Swift which has a grid of labels with single digit integers as the label text. I want to tap a label and have the integer increment.I've learned from a tutorial about a Tic Tac Toe app that I can overlay each label with a clear button (1-36) and use the taps to increment the labels (1-36) text number under it. So far so good. The tutorial uses a switch statement to pass in the tag of the button tapped and the cases are hardcoded to the Label references. This is fine for Tic Tac Toe because it's only a 3x3 grid but my grid is 6x6 and I'm too lazy to hard code all 36 cases. Is there a smarter way to pass in the button tags and perform this action?

I'm thinking of storing the button label text integers in an array and reading/writing/ to it then updating the label from there. This is probably better than what I have now but I don't think it solves my switch statement problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Label1: UILabel! //Row one
@IBOutlet var Label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label6: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Label7: UILabel!  //Row two
@IBOutlet var Label8: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label9: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label10: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label11: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label12: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Label13: UILabel!  //Row three
@IBOutlet var Label14: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label15: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label16: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label17: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label18: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Label19: UILabel!  //Row four
@IBOutlet var Label20: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label21: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label22: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label23: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label24: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Label25: UILabel!  //Row five
@IBOutlet var Label26: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label27: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label28: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label29: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label30: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Label31: UILabel!  //Row six
@IBOutlet var Label32: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label33: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label34: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label35: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Label36: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!  //Row one
@IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button6: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button7: UIButton!  //Row two
@IBOutlet var Button8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button9: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button10: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button11: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button12: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button13: UIButton!  //Row three
@IBOutlet var Button14: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button15: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button16: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button17: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button18: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button19: UIButton!  //Row four
@IBOutlet var Button20: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button21: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button22: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button23: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button24: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button25: UIButton!  //Row five
@IBOutlet var Button26: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button27: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button28: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button29: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button30: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button31: UIButton!  //Row six
@IBOutlet var Button32: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button33: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button34: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button35: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button36: UIButton!

@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    setLabelTextForButton(sender.tag)
}

func setLabelTextForButton(labelTag:Int) {
    switch labelTag{
    case 1:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label1.text.toInt()!
        if currentLabel == 9        // IF statement to reset to 0 if label is currently 9
        { currentLabel = 0
            Label1.text = String(currentLabel) }
        else {
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
            Label1.text = String(currentLabel)}
    case 2:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label2.text.toInt()! // OMG I have to code for all these buttons
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label2.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 3:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label3.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label3.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 4:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label4.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label4.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 5:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label5.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label5.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 6:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label6.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label6.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 7:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label7.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label7.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 8:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label8.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label8.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 9:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label9.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label9.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 10:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label10.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label10.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 11:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label11.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label11.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 12:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label12.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label12.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 13:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label13.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label13.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 14:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label14.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label14.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 15:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label15.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label15.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 16:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label16.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label16.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 17:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label17.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label17.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 18:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label18.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label18.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 19:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label19.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label19.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 20:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label20.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label20.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 21:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label21.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label21.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 22:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label22.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label22.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 23:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label23.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label23.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 24:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label24.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label24.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 25:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label25.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label25.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 26:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label26.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label26.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 27:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label27.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label27.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 28:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label28.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label28.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 29:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label29.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label29.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 30:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label30.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label30.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 31:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label31.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label31.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 32:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label32.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label32.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 33:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label33.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label33.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 34:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label34.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label34.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 35:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label35.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label35.text = String(currentLabel)
    case 36:
        var currentLabel:Int = Label36.text.toInt()!
        currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
        Label36.text = String(currentLabel)

    default: something something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the label property of the buttons instead of extra labels. This would look like this:

```
@IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!  //Row one
@IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button6: UIButton!
....

@IBAction func increaseLabel(sender: UIButton) {
    var currentLabel = sender.titleLabel.text.toInt()!
    currentLabel = currentLabel + 1
    sender.setTitle("\(currentLabel)", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Then connect all the buttons to that action in Interface Builder.

Comment: Maybe you should check the answer when you tried it and it worked. :)